# Eclipse RCP View doesn't show up on application's startup

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm facing this issue for about an hour now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Do you see the error in my plugin.xml code?

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="de.tps.client.workspace.perspective">
     <view
           closeable="true"
           id="de.tps.client.inboxplusplus.views.inboxplusplusview"
           minimized="false"
           moveable="true"
           ratio="0.3"
           relationship="bottom"
           relative="de.tps.client.iteminfo.view"
           showTitle="false"
           standalone="false"
           visible="true">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

And the view:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
        allowMultiple="false"
        category="com.contmgmt.client.category"
        class="de.tps.client.inboxplusplus.views.Inboxplusplusview"
        id="de.tps.client.inboxplusplus.views.inboxplusplusview"
        name="%view.inbox.name"
        restorable="true">
  </view>
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it work's fine. I guess you'll need to reset the perspective, because the old layout without this view is saved.

Click on the top-menu: Preferences -> Reset Perspective.

This information is stored in: `$workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml`