# eclipse editing area is limited to top right area

Tags: eclipse

Help!

My editing area of eclipse become very small, limited on the top right corner. While other areas are blank. Even if I try to maximize the editor (MainActivity.java), it is still limited at the top right corner, leaving other areas as blank.

I never encountered this problem before. Does anyone know how to restore to the default settings?

Thank you!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772523/eclipse-rcp-view-doesnt-show-up-on-applications-startup/16774413#16774413 try this if "reset perspective" don't work.

Comment: whats your eclipse version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Window menu, Reset Perspective

Answer (score 0):

> The Eclipse IDE has both workspace specific settings and generic IDE
>   settings.
>
> The workspace settings are saved inside the workspace folder which is
>   specified when Eclipse starts up the first time. These settings are
>   saved in a folder called '.metadata' inside the workspace location.
>   You can change the location of the workspace in Eclipse by using the
>   'File' menu and then clicking on the 'Switch Workspace' option.
>
> Note: If you delete your workspace folder you will also delete
>   projects located inside this folder. If you wish to preserve your
>   projects only delete the '.metadata' directory.
>
> Eclipse will save all the non workspace specific settings in a
>   different location. This will depend on whether you are using a Linux
>   or Windows environment.
>
> Windows*: C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\ARM\ARM
>   Workbench IDE Linux: /home//.awide
>
> You can safely delete the configuration folder to force Eclipse to
>   start up using the default settings. Eclipse will re-create the
>   configuration folder with all the configuration files.
>
> *For Windows 7 users: the C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data... directory has moved to C:\Users\\AppData...

from [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka11640.html)